# Double stroke math

Tags: math-mode, context

I recently started using ConTeXt and am trying to figure out how to place number sets. Namely, how do I get the natural number and real number sets to look like they do in LaTeX, (i.e. `\mathbb{N}` and `\mathbb{R}`)?

I found [doublestroke](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Doublestroke), but the font isn't quite the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Blackboard bold](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Blackboard_bold) page in `contextgarden`:

> Blackboard bold is probably the most common way of denoting the
>   "standard" number sets: the natural numbers, the integers and so on.
>   In AMS-LaTeX, you use the `\mathbb{...}` command to obtain them; the
>   ConTeXt way is the `\blackboard{...}` command. Also, the following
>   commands are defined:
>
> `\naturalnumbers`
>
> `\integers`
>
> `\rationals`
>
> `\reals`
>
> `\complexes`
>
> `\primes`
>
> `\blackboard{F}`
>
> `\blackboard{O}`

Comment: There is also the font switch `{\Bbb ...}`.